# Why for..of does not see non-numeric array indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say, I have array with non-numeric indexes:

```js
let arr = [12]
arr["fruit"] = "apple"
arr["off"] = false
```

#### 1. `for..of` does not see non-numeric indexes:

```js
for (let item of arr) {
  console.log(item)
}
```

• Output:

```
12
```

#### 2. Iterator does not see non-numeric indexes either:

```js
let iterator = arr[Symbol.iterator]()
let { value, done } = iterator.next()

while (!done) {
  console.log(value);
  ({ value, done } = iterator.next())
}
```

• Output:

```
12
```

### *However*:

#### 3. `Object.keys()` *does* see non-numeric indexes:

```js
for (let key of Object.keys(arr)) {
  console.log(`key: ${key}`)
}
```

• Output:

```
key: 0
key: fruit
key: off
```

#### 4. `Object.values()` sees values of all indexes:

```js
for (let value of Object.values(arr)) {
  console.log(`value: ${value}`)
}
```

• Output:

```
value: 12
value: apple
value: false
```

#### 5. `Object.entries()` sees *all* entries:

```js
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(arr)) {
  console.log(`key = ${key}, value = ${value}`)
}
```

• Output:

```
key = 0, value = 12
key = fruit, value = apple  
key = off, value = false
```

#### 6. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` also sees all non-numeric indexes:

```js
for (let prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr)) {
  console.log(prop)
}
```

• Output:

```
0
length
fruit
off
```

#### 7. These non-numeric indexes are enumerable:

```js
let descr

descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(arr, "fruit")
console.log(descr)

descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(arr, "off")
console.log(descr)
```

• Output

```
{
  value: 'apple',   
  writable: true,   
  enumerable: true, 
  configurable: true
}

{
  value: false,   
  writable: true,   
  enumerable: true, 
  configurable: true
}
```

Comment: Because they are not array indexes, they are object keys

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Could you elaborate more on this, please? 

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Quite simply because Arrays only use numeric values for indexes. Objects use key names. So `myArray["fruit"] = "apple";` is just wrong to do, while `myObject = {"fruit" : "apple"}` would be correct.

Comment: When you think you need to do this, you probably should rethink what you are doing. What is the real problem you are trying to solve with this format?

Comment: @epascarello I just was wondering about that. Of course, I will never use non-numeric keys for arrays. 

Comment: @JohnyL There is no such thing as a "non-numeric" key for an array. Array indexes are numeric (always) and keys are always strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use what you are describing as "non-numeric" indexes with an Array, you are mistaken as to what you are doing.

```js
let arr = [12];     // Set a variable equal to an array with only the number 12 in it
arr["fruit"] = "apple";  // Add a new custom property to your instance of an Array
arr["off"] = false       // Add a new custom property to your instance of an Array

console.log(arr[0]);        // 12
// Notice how the next 3 lines access properties of the Array, not indexed values?
console.log(arr.fruit);  // "apple"
console.log(arr.off);    // false
console.log(arr.length)     // There is only 1 array item, but 2 additional properties
```

Arrays only have numeric indexes, but they are objects so they also have properties. For example the `Array.length` property isn't something that shows up when you loop over the indexes.

So when you say: "Object.getOwnPropertyNames() also sees all non-numeric indexes", well, no, it doesn't. As the method name states, it gets all the property names that have been added to that unique instance of the object, not indexes. `Index != Property`.

If you want names to go with the values, you need to use `Object`, which has "keys", which can be any string value at all.